# How do I retrieve data from locked Lumia 520?

Tags: lumia, lumia-520

My husband passed away almost 2 yrs ago. I want to access his phone to retrieve precious and irreplaceable photos and messages but cannot remember his security passcode. Resetting the phone will lose everything. Please help.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this ? There's a vid online somewhere shows how to reset pin via onedrive somehow. Im trying to locate this tutorial so I can try it Im currently trying to recover some photos.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone isn't connected to a business (enterprise) account, you should be able to keep trying different passcodes until you hit the right one; it'll just take a long time. Other options that might be faster:

1. Does the phone have a microSD card installed? If so, it was likely being used for storing photos (the 520 doesn't have a lot of internal storage). You could remove that card, put it in a computer, and get its contents off that way.
2. Is the phone set up to back up its photos to OneDrive? If you have the password to the Microsoft account (if needed you can probably get Microsoft to unlock it for you, though that might take a while) you can check OneDrive to see if the photos got uploaded there, and download them if so.
3. If you want to get back the SMS (and they were being backed up), you can use another phone signed into the same Microsoft account (doesn't need to have the same PIN, or any PIN at all even) to restore them.

I feel like there really ought to be a way to unlock a Windows phone using the account password instead of the PIN, but I'm afraid I don't know of one.